# html5 video not working on tablet

Tags: android, html, ipad, video, html5-video

I have a website with a big video in the background and I used HTML5 video for it. It does all I want on desktops, I can't make it work on tablets though (don't need it on mobiles) - instead of a video I see a black background only.

Code below:

```
<div id="video-container">
<video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
<source src="http://link/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="http://link/vid.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
<source src="http://link/vid.webm" type="video/webm"/>
Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

Is it caused by the autoplay option? If so, is there any workaround?
Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most mobile browsers (including tablets - definitely iPad), autoplay will not work. The browser won't download *any* of the video file, not the first frame or even the metadata, until there's some kind of user interaction event - typically either a click or a touch.

The first thing you can do to alleviate the situation is to set a `poster` attribute on the video element, which is the URL to a poster image. That image should be visible right away in place of your video. If you want to go the extra mile, you can set a background color on the body so the user will see that while they're waiting for the poster image to load.

Next, you can add a touch or click event listener anywhere you want in the document that starts the video playing as soon as the user interacts with your web page.